# How can I update a tab's title when new content appears on minimized page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

When you have multiple tabs open some websites will update the tab title (i.e. with a "(1)" or "(2)") to indicate that content on the page has changed. I believe sites like Facebook and Buzzfeed do this (or am I just dreaming that they do that?)... How do they do it? Do they use JS? Is it possible to do something like that on a Wordpress site with a plugin that anyone is aware of?

Answer (score 1):

Just use:

```
document.title = "Whatever";
```

Reference:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.title

Comment: Yeah, but how do I detect that the page is minimized and that there has been new content added to it since the user last viewed the page?

Comment: @Fred The websites you reference use some sort of communication with the server. There's nothing special that the tab is minimized or not in focus - the same thing happens if that tab is active. Either the page is polling the server to see if there's new content (AJAX), using WebSockets, or a method of Comet. It's up to you to talk to the server to find out if there's new content and update the `document.title` appropriately